# How to extract the substring preceding marker?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a string:

- [3016] - Device is ready...
- [10ice is loading..13] - v3[3016] - Device is ready...
- [1r 0.[3016] - Device is ready.
  Everything except '[3016] - Device is ready...' is 'noise'
  The key word here is "Device is ready"
  3016 - timestamp in msec. I need to extract '3016' from string for further operations

Tried following:

```
if "Device is ready" in reply:
    # set a pattern for extracting time from the result
    found = re.findall("\[.*\]", reply)
    # Cut timestemp from reply
    x = [tm[1:-1] for tm in found]
```

in case the reply was 'clean' (**[3016] - Device is ready...**) it's ok, but if there is 'noise' in reply then it doesn't work. Can someone point me in the right direction or perhaps assist with the code? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a single key, and it should precede the marker `Device is ready`, you can capture the digits first.

```
\[(\d+)].*\bDevice is ready\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\[(\d+)]` Capture 1+ digits between square brackets in **group 1**
- `.*` Match 0+ times any char
- `\bDevice is ready\b`  and then `Device is ready`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sp9fXY/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/BWxb6M)

```
import re

strings = [
    "[3016] - Device is ready...",
    "[10ice is loading..13] - v3[3017] - Device is ready...",
    "[1r 0.[3018] - Device is ready.",
    "[1r 0 - Device is ready. [3019]",
]

pattern = r"\[(\d+)].*\bDevice is ready\b"
for s in strings:
    match = re.search(pattern, s)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1))
```

Output

```
3016
3017
3018
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work!
In my case, this is not a list of strings, but a separate string, it will be always one of the listed strings. How in this case adjust the code

Comment: In my case, this is not a list, but a separate string, it will be always one of the listed strings. How in this case adjust the code?

Comment: @Roman In that case you can use a single string. See https://ideone.com/Qcyfz4

Answer (score 1):

You should use a regex group `()` to extract the number. `found` will be a list of all the numbers found inside `[]`:

```
if "Device is ready" in reply:
    # set a pattern for extracting time from the result
    found = re.findall("\[(\d+)\]", reply)

print(found[0])
```

Comment: this should also work if the number is stored as a string?